# What is the meaning of 'clear' in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I couldn't find a proper meaning to the word **clear** in this paragraph.

> European officials are looking at whether the banks, including Barclays and Goldman Sachs, have harmed rival organizations that could compete in the markets for providing information on and **clearing** a form of transaction that has become critical to the smooth functioning of financial markets.

Definitions: *To give or get official permission for something to be done.*

Is this definition suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In banking, to 'clear' a transaction of money is to transfer that money completely from one account (the sender's) to another (the recipient's). At the end of that process, it becomes 'cleared funds' in the recipient's account.

[Cleared funds (Investopedia)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cleared-funds.asp#:%7E:text=Cleared%20funds%20are%20money%20that,the%20receiver%20of%20the%20funds.)